# on button click notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, push-notification

I am making an application in android using eclipse IDE and i want to implement a notification in my android i want to make the notification on button click example i want to notify saved data..i found this tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateNotification) i copied the code and paste it in my setOnClickListener code..but im getting error..i dont know how to start doing this because in the tutorial they just give you the code snippet..this is my code

**UPDATE QUESTION**

what is the difference between notification and push notification and which is better to use..

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mNotifyManager =
                            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Picture Download")
                        .setContentText("Download in progress")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
                    // Start a lengthy operation in a background thread
                    new Thread(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                int incr;
                                // Do the "lengthy" operation 20 times
                                for (incr = 0; incr <= 100; incr+=5) {
                                        // Sets the progress indicator to a max value, the
                                        // current completion percentage, and "determinate"
                                        // state
                                        mBuilder.setProgress(100, incr, false);
                                        // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
                                        mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
                                            // Sleeps the thread, simulating an operation
                                            // that takes time
                                            try {
                                                // Sleep for 5 seconds
                                                Thread.sleep(5*1000);
                                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                                            }
                                }
                                // When the loop is finished, updates the notification
                                mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
                                // Removes the progress bar
                                        .setProgress(0,0,false);
                                mNotifyManager.notify(ID, mBuilder.build());
                            }
                        }
                    // Starts the thread by calling the run() method in its Runnable
                    ).start();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Post your logcat then.

Comment: i dont have log cat yet because i still have error actually im doing it and starting to get rid of some errors by reading other tutorial but some error wont go..is it possible that i am missing something here

Comment: ya it's possible but what are the errors you getting?

Comment: i get error in mNotifyManager and mBuilder all of them do i need to put it on oncreate this is my only code..

Comment: ok you just create this Objects outside button onclick

Comment: you mean i make a public void notification(){} and put the code inside?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54484/discussion-between-simple-plan-and-hak-hak).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change this

```
 mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
```

to

```
 mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(youractivity.this);
```

You need to pass current `Context` for creating `mBuilder` object.